# Spring MVC 3.0 Model attribute is unexpectedly converted from List to String in JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Using Spring MVC 3.0, from my controller when I add a `List` object as an attribute to my model, it gets converted to a `String` in my JSP template.

Here's a simplified version of my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reservationQuery")
public class ReservationQueryController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void setupForm(Model model) {
        List<Reservation> reservations = java.util.Collections.emptyList();
        model.addAttribute("reservations", reservations);
    }
}
```

A breakpoint on the last line confirms that the `reservations` variable is an empty `List`.  Here is reservationQuery.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<c:forEach items="${reservations}" var="reservation">
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

A breakpoint at the beginning of the `c:forEach` loop shows that the `List`, `reservations`, was converted to the `String` representation of an empty list, "[]".  Why?

Just as strange is the fact that the page attempts an iteration, even though a string is not iterable (well maybe it is by character, but that's not what's happening).  Even if I set `reservations` to an empty string it also tries to do an iteration.  Of course, it throws an exception within the loop when I try to access a property of `reservation` that does not exist.  In both cases, `reservation` was set to a string with the value "{reservations}".  WTF?

1. Why is the `reservations` attribute converted from a `List` to a `String`?
2. And why does the JSP do an iteration of a string, setting the `forEach` variable to the literal string "{reservations}"?

Comment: I don't do Spring MVC, but I'd be interested what debugger you were using. Maybe it's your or debugger's misinterpreation of the EL expression. Try to do `<c:out value="${reservations.class.name}" />` and see what implementation class it prints. Also, does the iteration work if the list contains items?

Comment: Maybe you have EL disabled in your configuration. You can use <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %> in the JSP.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  The problem was a missing `$` at `items="${reservations}"`.  I closed my IDE and it asked me to save the changes in my JSP.  I was suspicious because I always save after each change.  I said yes, but when I reopened the IDE some of my changes were missing, including that one.  I copied and pasted my code into my question, so you can see that it was there.  I hate these type of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point I changed this mistake:

```
<c:forEach items="reservations" var="reservation">
```

To this:

```
<c:forEach items="${reservations}" var="reservation">
```

But my IDE was not saving changes to my JSP file until I restarted my computer.  After restarting and fixing the line, I was fine.  I had some pending Windows updates and I wonder if that had anything to do with it.